# How to remove Python 3.6 completely from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04

Both Python 2.7 and 3.6 are installed by default in Ubuntu 18. But I wish to use the Anaconda Python with conda package manager. To avoid any conflicts I wish to completely remove the default Python 3.6. Are there any way to do that? Please help.

Comment: That's the wrong approach with a very high chance. Did you read some anaconda docs?

Comment: I recall reading that 18.04 now defaults to 3.6. By _extremely_ cautious in removing it, as you may cause serious issues.

Comment: The *right* question is "how do I keep multiple Python installations separate".

Comment: Why would you ever want to use anaconda on Linux? Its raison d'etre is "Windows sucks for building", and even that is obsoleted by recent pip developments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 requires python 3.6 to function. If you remove python 3.6, you won't be able to log in after a restart. Ubuntu will still have python 3.6minimal, even after uninstalling python 3.6. so you will have to remove both. Once that is done, you'll get an error that looks like this.

https://itsfoss.com/failed-to-start-session-ubuntu-14-04/

You can follow the above steps if you break Ubuntu.

Answer (score 26):

Don't do that , just don't.
you'll have regrets a lot of it.
And I'm serious.
A lot of things will deleted,but by the way, if you already done that don't worry,  there is a solutions.
Just run this code in your terminal

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

And if you want you can run this one too

```
#ubuntu-18.04.1
sudo apt install $( curl http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest | sed -e 's#\t.*##g' )
```

Link for reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087267/how-do-i-reinstall-the-software-packages-that-came-with-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Unfortunately, I did this and many things were removed. I can not run any command of installation because it has error `E: Unmet dependencies`. What is should i do?