# how to make sudo works again?

Tags: python, debian, sudo, uninstallation

Half of my OS does not work anymore after I used this command to uninstall python

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python
```

like the sudo does not work 
I gave it this command

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory
```

and my LXDE does not work 
and the network does not work anymore

what should I do?

Comment: Are you on Ubunto? If yes, the OS needs Python to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298011/how-to-remove-python-3-6-completely-from-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @FBSO on debian 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python, perl and sh/bash/dash are the main interpreters of debian. Many essential scripts and packages of debian depend on one of those three. You must not remove it, but only when you are really know what you are doing. You can install it again with:

```sh
#become root with
su -
apt-get install python
```

You have probably also removed your desktop environment. Launch taskel from the commandline as root to install a desktop environment of your choice.

Comment: I found a way to reinstall the sudo command, but I had to restart the pc and now I can't connect to the internet because the network manager was deleted too. so I can't install anything now :/

Comment: Then you have to use a ethernet connection, but you should still try my answer. Maybe you are lucky and the removed packages are still cached by apt on your machine.